# Complex(?) Eclipse Launch Configuration

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have two Eclipse Projects where one is a Spring Project that is deployed on a server and the second is a normal Java Application.
If I change something on my server I always need to restart the server and then start the Java Application manually. Is it possible to start both with "one click"?
Also, is it possible that if I launch a program the previous launched program is killed before?

Thanks,
heinrich

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an ant script:

- Deploy Spring project
- Restart Server
- Restart App

Every application server comes with appropriate ant task, in your case deploying a project and restarting the server. Restarting your application depends on the type.

You can then run the script in the "External Tools Configuration" and you have a one click solution.

Comment: Are these 3 points a sequence of steps or single options each? If using ANT will I have the convenient Eclipse Console for Std In/ Std Out to my Java Program?

Comment: Yes, they're in sequence as far as I can tell and yes, you'd get console output from Ant.